# Why is there no desert in Southeast China?

Tags: wind, rainfall, rain

Arabia, Sahara and Southeast China and India all are on the tropic of Cancer yet Southeast China and India are not deserts. I know that India is not a desert because of monsoon wind which causes heavy rain. But China doesn't have that kind of wind. Also Tibet which is in Southwest China is very dry because the moist air doesn't get over the Himalayas. But east of that you would normally expect there to be another big desert, but there isn't. Why is this?

Comment: are you referring to this area -https://wikitravel.org/en/Southeast_China ? China gets it's own monsoon from the water body east of it. The Chinese and Indian monsoon are related but have different mechanisms

Comment: Why do you think there should be a desert? [Why are deserts mostly located on the western side of continents?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9994/why-are-deserts-mostly-located-on-the-western-side-of-continents) deals with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very active region for tropical storms.
[image: https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/7000/7079/tropical_cyclone_map_lrg.gif]
[NASA](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/images/7079/historic-tropical-cyclone-tracks)

Comment: -1 but I am not down voting how does this answer the question asked ? This plot tells me there is rain in SE China but OP is asking for desert.

Comment: @gansub am I missing something? Op asks why is there no desert, and the answer shows there is rain. What’s the problem here?

Comment: @Gimelist - Heck if i know. I asked the OP to clarify the region he/she is referring to. No answer. Then I asked Keith to explain the answer better as opposed to writing posting a link. No answer. China has it's own monsoon due to several unique factors. SE China gets rain due to moisture laden winds from East China Sea